# Redis delete item from zset using value

Tags: python, redis

Using Python how to delete an item in `Redis` sorted set using its value.

Suppose I have a sorted zset `"user:<user_name>"` with priority stored like this
`"user:<user_name>" -> [(value_1, priority_1), (value_2, priority_2)]`

Now I want to delete value_2 from `"user:<user_name>"`

Comment: What's wrong with ZREM?

Comment: I don't know about zREM can you give one example

Comment: Check "examples" here: http://redis.io/commands/zrem